# Computational Logistic Regression With Python, Different Sample Sizes

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

Currently, I am trying to implement a basic logistic regression algorithm in Python to differentiate between A vs. B.

For my training and test data, I have ~50,000 samples of A vs. 1000 samples of B. Is this a problem if I use half the data of each to train the algorithm and the other half as testing data (25000 train A, 500 train B and so on for testing accuracy).

If so, how can I overcome this problem. Should I consider resampling, doing some other "fancy stuff".

Comment: Are there any distinctions between the data in samples A and B? Or did those samples come from the same dataset and you preemptively split them into separate samples with the intent of having one be used for training and the other for testing?

Comment: There are no distinctions. Sample A and B came from the same source, but the data is different in the sense that something different was happening in each sample (e.g. sample A has data when you're healthy, sample B has data when you have sickness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much of a problem it is depends on the nature of your data. The bigger issue will be that you simply have a huge class imbalance (50 As for every B). If you end up getting good classification accuracy anyway, then fine - nothing to do. What to do next depends on your data and the nature of the problem and what is acceptable in a solution. There really isn't a dead set "do this" answer for this question.

Comment: The accuracy is very low, but I do not know if it is due to this matter?